# Why are my files in a different "~\Library\Mobile Documents" folder?

Tags: ensembles

This is an image of my ~\Library\Mobile Documents folder on my desktop:

[image]

Why are my files under *com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.clouddata*  rather than *BookstoreInventoryManager* (which is my app name?)  Is something set wrong in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll note that there are two BookstoreInventorManager directories. The top one is the mobile documents for your app. You can see that the ensembles folder is inside that one.

I suspect you are creating the other one yourself. There is no harm to this.

Answer (score 0):

*[Ensembles](http://www.ensembles.io)* is a cloud syncing library built by Dutch ISV [The Mental Faculty, BV](https://www.mentalfaculty.com/).

If you do a `find ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents -iname '*mentalfaculty*'` you might find some apps using it (e.g., the famous [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/)).

> Ensembles 2 is a drop-in replacement for the open-source Ensembles 1.x framework

So, as to why your data is in the Ensembles folder rather than someplace else, I suspect it is using the default directory name, and you haven't changed it.  If you don't think you are using that package, then maybe some library you are using does, without you knowing.